# Highchart not rendering in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am not able to render highchart in my shinyapp using r. I am trying alot to make it work. But the panel is just showing the headings and credits except the chart. Can anyone please help. Here is my code:

```
    library(dplyr)
    library(ggplot2)
    library(highcharter)
    library(maps)
    library(scales)
    library(DT)

    require(ggthemes)

    d <- read.csv(file = "cities_r2.csv")
    df <-separate(data = d, col = location, into = c("lat","lng"),sep = ",")
    df$name_of_city <- trimws(df$name_of_city)

    ui <- fluidPage(
      h1("Top 500 Indian Cities"),

      mainPanel(highchartOutput(outputId = "plot1", height = "800px"))

    )

    server <- function(input, output, session) {
      output$plot1 <- renderHighchart({  
        ds <- df %>% 
              group_by(state_name) %>% 
              summarise(total = sum(population_total)) %>% 
              arrange(desc(total))

        sx<-ds$state_name
        sy<-ds$total


        hchart(ds, x = sx, y = sy, type = "column", color = sx) %>%
          hc_title(text = "States by number of cities in Top 500") %>%
          hc_add_theme(hc_theme_google())


        hchart(ds, x = sx, value = sy, color = sy, type = "treemap")  %>% hc_add_theme(hc_theme_google()) %>%
          hc_credits(enabled = TRUE, text = "Sources: Census India 2011", style = list(fontSize = "10px")) %>%
          hc_title(text = "States by Number of Cities in Top 500")


      })
    }


    shinyApp(server = server, ui = ui)
```

[Here is how my app looks like at present](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJiCI.png)

This is my session info

```
    > sessionInfo()
    R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
    Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
    Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

    locale:
    [1] LC_COLLATE=English_India.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_India.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_India.1252
    [4] LC_NUMERIC=C                   LC_TIME=English_India.1252    

    attached base packages:
    [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

    other attached packages:
     [1] magrittr_1.5      rCharts_0.4.5     devtools_1.12.0   ggthemes_3.3.0    leaflet_1.0.1     tidyr_0.6.1      
     [7] DT_0.2            scales_0.4.1      maps_3.1.1        ggplot2_2.2.1     dplyr_0.5.0       shiny_1.0.0.9000 
    [13] highcharter_0.5.0

    loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
     [1] Rcpp_0.12.9         git2r_0.18.0        plyr_1.8.4          tools_3.3.2         xts_0.9-7          
     [6] digest_0.6.11       memoise_1.0.0       lubridate_1.6.0     jsonlite_1.2        tibble_1.2         
    [11] nlme_3.1-129        gtable_0.2.0        lattice_0.20-34     psych_1.6.12        igraph_1.0.1       
    [16] DBI_0.5-1           curl_2.3            yaml_2.1.14         parallel_3.3.2      httr_1.2.1         
    [21] withr_1.0.2         stringr_1.1.0       htmlwidgets_0.8     grid_3.3.2          data.table_1.10.0  
    [26] R6_2.2.0            foreign_0.8-67      RJSONIO_1.3-0       whisker_0.3-2       reshape2_1.4.2     
    [31] purrr_0.2.2         TTR_0.23-1          htmltools_0.3.5     rlist_0.4.6.1       rsconnect_0.7      
    [36] assertthat_0.1      quantmod_0.4-7      mnormt_1.5-5        colorspace_1.3-2    mime_0.5           
    [41] xtable_1.8-2        httpuv_1.3.3        stringi_1.1.2       lazyeval_0.2.0.9000 munsell_0.4.3      
    [46] broom_0.4.1         zoo_1.7-14
```

Comment: can you provide what `cities_r2.csv` looks like?

Comment: Do `dput(df)` please and post it with your question

Comment: @PorkChop You can see the file in this link

[citiesr2](http://www.filedropper.com/citiesr2)

Comment: You can download the data set in the above link

Comment: you also missing packages in your example such as `library(shiny)
library(tidyr)
library(trimws)`

Comment: I added `library(shiny) library(tidyr) `, but not `library(trimws)` , as there was no such package and its still showing the same output screen.

Comment: @PorkChop The `dput(df)` output is 
`> dput(df)
function (x, df1, df2, ncp, log = FALSE) 
{
    if (missing(ncp)) 
        .Call(C_df, x, df1, df2, log)
    else .Call(C_dnf, x, df1, df2, ncp, log)
}`

Comment: Hi all, in the highcharter v0.5.0, when you use `hchart` function with a data frame, you need now use `hcaes` to set mappings. See please https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/highcharter/vignettes/charting-data-frames.html. So, for example you need something like ` hchart(ds, "column", hcaes(x = sx, y = sy. color = sx))`

Comment: Thanks @jbkunst, I changed the code as u mentioned and its working

Comment: You're welcome. Next time try to put the error from the console in the question so the others can help you quickly ;B